# Is it possible to convert a PPT to a video file with Interop Services without having PowerPoint installed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, powerpoint, office-interop

Everything I've read on the matter says that PowerPoint has to be installed and ready to launch when using the Interop Services in a C# script to convert a PPT to a video file. Obviously I'd much rather PowerPoint not to be required for this script to successfully effect its conversion. Below is my code. Any advice is greatly appreciated:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application ppApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
ppApp.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
ppApp.WindowState = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpWindowState.ppWindowMinimized;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations oPresSet = ppApp.Presentations;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Presentation oPres = oPresSet.Open(fileName,
    MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse,
    MsoTriState.msoFalse);
try
{
    oPres.CreateVideo(exportPath);
}
```

Comment: Short answer:  No.  You have, in essence, the key to the car and want to use it to take you places.  The key may be necessary, but to get there, you'll need the car too.  You can't drive PowerPoint w/o a PowerPoint to drive.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg If I am not very mistaking [LibreOffice Impress](http://www.libreoffice.org/features/impress/) among other programs can independently from commercial Microsoft Powerpoint open and display a PowerPoint Presentation. Why would it hence not be possible to script it for instance to make a video. The file data at least can be read, so it is just a tiny step to then turn it into a video. Granded of course the code for that would not be a MS-Script.

Comment: The question specifically asks about automating PowerPoint. It might be possible to open a PowerPoint file in some other program and IF that program is able to be automated and IF it can output video, then sure, it might be possible to do the job that way.  I don't know that I'd call it a "tiny step" however.